# ExtJS Container set existing content as items

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

I m really new in ExtJS and try to reuse some existing content produced with jQuery. Is there a simple way to add existing components as items in a container?

My code looks something like this

```
var rect = $('<div>', {
    'id' : 'rectangle'
}).text("this is a rectangle.");

var cont = new Ext.Container({
    layout : 'absolute',
    width : 400,
    height : 300,
    renderTo : Ext.getBody(),
    border : 1,
    style : {
        borderColor : '#000000',
        borderStyle : 'solid',
        borderWidth : '1px'
    },
    items : [{
        html : rect
    }]
});
```

Comment: Do you mean the html from within that `rect`? Would `html: rect.html()` work?

Comment: Its working, but produces only the raw content. Is there also a way to apply the defined CSS styles?

Comment: Hmm that might have something to do with your CSS rules for it & extJS. Inspect the element, to see if maybe extJS is even overruling your styles.

Comment: Yes, u r right. Ext overrides the content and makes `<div id="ext-gen563" class="x-panel-body x-panel-body-noheader" style="width: 396px;">this is a rectangle.</div>`. Is there a way to apply the old CSS rules?

Comment: You might need to do something like `.html('<div id="someID">this is a rectangle.</div>')` to achieve that, I'm not 100% sure!

Answer (score 2):

Simply grab the html of that item with `.html()`

```
items : [{
    html : rect.html()
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use `contentEl`. Note that this moves the element inside the component, so when the component is destroyed, so is the element.

```
items: {
    contentEl: rect.get(0) // Grab a reference to the DOM element
}
```

If you want to make a copy, of the element before moving it, you could call:
`rect.clone.get(0);`